# Expectation of the maximum consecutive subsequence sum of a random sequence

Tags: algorithm, programming-pearls

Here is a problem from Programming Pearls 2nd edition (Chapter 8.7):

> Considering a real number sequence, whose elements are drawn uniformly from the range `[-1, 1]`, what is the expected maximum consecutive subsequence sum? (If all the elements are negative, the maximum sum is `0`.)

Assuming the length of the sequence is `N`, is there a closed form for the expected maximum subsequence sum `f(N)`? I try to do some simulation, but failed to find any clue.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should post this on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is similar to [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) in 1D, but with an unusual distribution for step sizes.  for large N it approximates a [Wiener process](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WienerProcess.html).

(not sure any of that is very helpful, but if you're not aware of the connections it may give additional places to look).

Answer (score 0):

Perform a number of simulation and save all the results. Put them into a  [Histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)  and you will see that some values have the property to appear more frequently. Because of the randomness you have to perform a larger number of tests so your histogram to become more reliable( even then I am not sure of the fairness of the result).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also submitted in [Quora](http://www.quora.com). The link is [here](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-expected-value-of-the-sum-of-the-maximum-sum-subvector-if-the-arrays-elements-are-random-real-numbers-chosen-uniformly-from-1-1#)

One of the replies is about simulation:

Here are exact answers for a few small cases, courtesy of Mathematica. Unfortunately the computation becomes very slow after these.

```
In[1]:= f[n_] := Expectation[Max[0, Max[Table[Sum[x[k], {k, i, j}], {i, n}, {j, i, n}]]], Distributed[Table[x[i], {i, n}], UniformDistribution[Table[{-1, 1}, {n}]]]]

In[2]:= Table[f[n], {n, 5}]

Out[2]= {1/4, 1/2, 23/32, 291/320, 4141/3840}
```